Full authentication is required to access this resource on custom_authenticator
Using Pimcore 11.3
Trying to implement a Slack Login SSO mechanism. Pimcore Admin UI does not accept my token or authorization which I implemented through AbstractAuthenticator
What I did:

Created a custom bundle and overwritten login.html.twig for "Sign in with Slack" button (OK)
Created a SlackAuthenticator by extending AbstractAuthenticator and written methods with Slack Oauth2 logic (OK)
Created a matching user with my Slack user (using e-mail) and tested logging in with Slack (OK, at least at log level, I can see that e-mail matches Pimcore user fine, and onAuthenticationSuccess is called)
**- Could not manage transferring logged in user to Pimcore Admin UI (Full authentication is required to access this resource.)
**

security:
    enable_authenticator_manager: true

    providers:
        pimcore_admin:
            id: Pimcore\Security\User\UserProvider

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        # Pimcore WebDAV HTTP basic // DO NOT CHANGE!
        pimcore_webdav:
            pattern: ^/asset/webdav
            provider: pimcore_admin
            http_basic: ~

        # Slack OAuth Firewall
        slack_oauth:
            pattern: ^/slack/callback$
            provider: pimcore_admin
            stateless: false
            custom_authenticator: App\Security\SlackAuthenticator

        # Pimcore Admin Bundle firewall
        pimcore_admin: '%pimcore_admin_bundle.firewall_settings%'

    access_control:
        # Pimcore admin ACl  // DO NOT CHANGE!
        - { path: ^/admin/settings/display-custom-logo, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
        - { path: ^/admin/login/2fa-verify, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_2FA_IN_PROGRESS }
        - { path: ^/admin/login/2fa-setup, roles: ROLE_PIMCORE_USER }
        - { path: ^/admin/login/2fa, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_2FA_IN_PROGRESS }
        - { path: ^/admin/login$, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
        - { path: ^/admin/login/(login|lostpassword|deeplink|csrf-token)$, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_PIMCORE_USER }
        - { path: ^/asset/webdav, roles: ROLE_PIMCORE_USER }
        - { path: ^/slack/callback$, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
        - { path: ^/slack/login, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }

    role_hierarchy:
        # Pimcore admin  // DO NOT CHANGE!
        ROLE_PIMCORE_ADMIN: [ROLE_PIMCORE_USER]

// removed "if" checks in many places for sake of readability
class SlackAuthenticator extends AbstractAuthenticator
{
    private $httpClient;
    private $urlGenerator;
    private $userProvider;

    public function __construct(PimcoreHttpClient $httpClient,UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator,UserProviderInterface $userProvider,
    ) {
        $this->httpClient = $httpClient;
        $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
        $this->userProvider = $userProvider;
    }

    public function supports(Request $request): ?bool
    {
        return ($request->getPathInfo() === '/slack/callback' && $request->isMethod('GET'));
    }
    
    public function authenticate(Request $request): Passport
    {
        $code = $request->query->get('code');
        $response = $this->httpClient->post('https://slack.com/api/oauth.v2.access', [
            'form_params' => [
                'client_id' => $_SERVER['SLACK_CLIENT_ID'],
                'client_secret' => $_SERVER['SLACK_CLIENT_SECRET'],
                'code' => $code,
                'redirect_uri' => $this->urlGenerator->generate('slack_callback', [], UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL),
            ],
        ]);
        $data = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
        $accessToken = $data['authed_user']['access_token'] ?? null;
        $user_id = $data['authed_user']['id'] ?? null;
        $response = $this->httpClient->get('https://slack.com/api/users.info', [
            'headers' => [
                'Authorization' => "Bearer {$_SERVER['SLACK_BOT_USER_OAUTH_TOKEN']}",
            ],
            'query' => [
                'user' => $user_id,
            ],
        ]);
        $userData = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
        $email = $userData['user']['profile']['email'] ?? null;
        $user = $this->userProvider->loadUserByIdentifier($email);
        return new SelfValidatingPassport(new UserBadge($email, function () use ($user) {
            return $user;
        }));
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, string $firewallName): ?Response
    {
        return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('pimcore_admin_index'));
    }

    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception): ?Response
    {
        return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('pimcore_admin_login'));
    }
}



Have you checked if your logged in user has a role ROLE_PIMCORE_USER  ?

Definitely. Tried with user and admin roles. Authentication completely succeeds.
I also pasted security logs in pimcore/pimcore GitHub discussion..
https://github.com/orgs/pimcore/discussions/17513
